# How to subset a data frame by similar coordinates of a plot in R?

Tags: r

## Problem

Following plot represents an oscillation loop where in there are at least 2 instances when the coordinates (x= relative.v, y=gap.dist) are  approximately similar:
[image]

The plot is based on following data frame:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Vehicle.ID = c(3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 
3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L, 3002L
), Frame.ID = 8931:9277, gap.dist = c(14.26, 14.25, 14.18, 14.38, 
14.73, 15.34, 15.75, 16.07, 16.14, 16.28, 16.42, 16.58, 16.71, 
16.77, 16.75, 16.73, 16.78, 16.83, 16.77, 16.56, 16.28, 16.09, 
16.02, 16.03, 16.06, 16.08, 16.02, 15.8, 15.48, 15.08, 14.79, 
14.66, 14.76, 15, 15.29, 15.58, 15.86, 16.13, 16.4, 16.69, 17.01, 
17.39, 17.77, 18.18, 18.63, 19.1, 19.55, 19.87, 20.06, 20.14, 
20.06, 19.83, 19.52, 19.47, 19.57, 19.85, 20.24, 20.56, 20.76, 
20.8, 20.78, 20.82, 21.01, 21.31, 21.76, 22.27, 22.78, 23.24, 
23.81, 24.54, 25.36, 25.93, 26.35, 26.58, 26.63, 26.63, 26.61, 
26.6, 26.61, 26.63, 26.68, 26.76, 26.84, 26.88, 26.88, 26.86, 
26.86, 26.87, 26.84, 26.69, 26.39, 25.98, 25.55, 25.22, 25.05, 
24.96, 24.83, 24.61, 24.37, 24.19, 24.09, 24.03, 23.94, 23.81, 
23.6, 23.36, 23.14, 23, 22.96, 22.93, 22.85, 22.89, 23.09, 23.42, 
23.96, 24.47, 24.98, 25.48, 25.99, 26.49, 26.93, 27.29, 27.58, 
27.84, 28.12, 28.35, 28.5, 28.52, 28.49, 28.49, 28.49, 28.51, 
28.51, 28.46, 28.26, 27.94, 27.49, 27.04, 26.69, 26.46, 26.29, 
26.15, 26.05, 25.95, 25.77, 25.46, 25.01, 24.51, 23.99, 23.48, 
22.97, 22.46, 22.01, 21.71, 21.52, 21.46, 21.47, 21.5, 21.5, 
21.46, 21.35, 21.2, 21, 20.82, 20.73, 20.72, 20.77, 20.81, 20.83, 
20.84, 20.87, 20.93, 20.99, 20.98, 20.81, 20.51, 20.09, 19.5, 
18.84, 18.22, 17.67, 17.2, 16.76, 16.31, 15.85, 15.37, 14.87, 
14.4, 14.09, 13.92, 13.89, 14.04, 14.27, 14.44, 14.52, 14.53, 
14.51, 14.49, 14.48, 14.54, 14.73, 15.03, 15.48, 15.99, 16.51, 
17.01, 17.51, 18.01, 18.51, 19, 19.49, 19.97, 20.49, 21, 21.42, 
21.8, 22.2, 22.68, 23.22, 23.72, 24.16, 24.46, 24.64, 24.7, 24.71, 
24.69, 24.7, 24.79, 24.91, 24.99, 25, 25.04, 25.23, 25.54, 25.98, 
26.47, 26.96, 27.42, 27.88, 28.31, 28.71, 29.13, 29.6, 30.1, 
30.67, 31.22, 31.74, 32.22, 32.7, 33.18, 33.65, 34.14, 34.63, 
35.1, 35.48, 35.77, 35.93, 36.01, 36.02, 36.01, 35.99, 35.98, 
35.97, 36.03, 36.22, 36.53, 36.97, 37.48, 38, 38.5, 39, 39.5, 
40, 40.5, 41, 41.5, 42.02, 42.52, 42.95, 43.27, 43.55, 43.9, 
44.32, 44.71, 45.04, 45.32, 45.68, 46.13, 46.64, 47.15, 47.66, 
48.16, 48.66, 49.14, 49.59, 50.11, 50.76, 51.53, 52.39, 53.23, 
53.89, 54.33, 54.59, 54.69, 54.67, 54.65, 54.67, 54.63, 54.41, 
53.99, 53.32, 52.45, 51.37, 50.34, 49.58, 49.04, 48.75, 48.59, 
48.45, 48.33, 48.29, 48.35, 48.44, 48.5, 48.51, 48.5, 48.5, 48.5, 
48.5, 48.48, 48.5, 48.59, 48.7, 48.79, 48.81, 48.79, 48.79, 48.81, 
48.81, 48.76, 48.66, 48.48, 48.2, 47.9, 47.66, 47.53, 47.45), 
    relative.v = c(-0.231958711994036, -0.358786482018626, -0.493043858010829, 
    -0.603994747669997, -0.6834873406704, -0.704230725717888, 
    -0.683630108352705, -0.641990970504217, -0.605163689204243, 
    -0.567161947335347, -0.529429778626142, -0.482298368556108, 
    -0.42647331081773, -0.369173963973488, -0.317864145436122, 
    -0.27215092988564, -0.222271462250546, -0.165391992820446, 
    -0.108707037952307, -0.0675612213625278, -0.0477147206681607, 
    -0.0414454276080818, -0.0476618292889057, -0.067647250925063, 
    -0.0952135763957465, -0.132233210872627, -0.169032614951778, 
    -0.224558129705247, -0.305892089806985, -0.433192920594433, 
    -0.597058648138646, -0.784350388317396, -0.973527586046128, 
    -1.14462631936783, -1.29678622625557, -1.42761898722476, 
    -1.54906644175957, -1.6650595720809, -1.78209545480779, -1.88940628918218, 
    -1.97722871863032, -2.04225189672011, -2.08546695327304, 
    -2.1044860500428, -2.09796964248165, -2.06190787822558, -1.99844917265652, 
    -1.92193672217891, -1.84742373905972, -1.78780164244319, 
    -1.75565255090781, -1.7629350542013, -1.81635437869936, -1.89059599593372, 
    -1.97208540466579, -2.04481870206861, -2.09849716157203, 
    -2.14227073017713, -2.18512621990102, -2.24263101599094, 
    -2.31718949145358, -2.40514550573653, -2.49340510959946, 
    -2.57436989675751, -2.63544848011734, -2.6689901513396, -2.67350192589669, 
    -2.65699261834573, -2.608778757795, -2.51116460703307, -2.35312028472961, 
    -2.15792890969266, -1.93944582008588, -1.71401090565721, 
    -1.49897671478181, -1.30013098178194, -1.11987964932729, 
    -0.958163046295219, -0.809121425603362, -0.667803469072645, 
    -0.534495948291298, -0.405846360762691, -0.278032061203845, 
    -0.147624784135722, -0.0159661005255529, 0.116484810737678, 
    0.250849865326245, 0.384569960495014, 0.513832535556414, 
    0.628179368957984, 0.717238699454732, 0.772469483794143, 
    0.794081521859322, 0.790585433247973, 0.779778716786936, 
    0.769281747503701, 0.75462248893114, 0.723104131773244, 0.674524493111942, 
    0.616240015693645, 0.553447905749508, 0.481734241451385, 
    0.402808385044558, 0.311768591287493, 0.201557809654801, 
    0.070410636092415, -0.0823411571070167, -0.252235867028997, 
    -0.430192410178485, -0.616230547265296, -0.816932548764832, 
    -1.02128173816849, -1.21482132000639, -1.38472075536161, 
    -1.50943429334364, -1.59116024170469, -1.63280226450591, 
    -1.63605837201801, -1.60185887314092, -1.5328995122303, -1.43474942568578, 
    -1.31516263316973, -1.1799595548971, -1.02883334458002, -0.857296537717993, 
    -0.668656397373574, -0.472193386647078, -0.279835637875358, 
    -0.092896649784354, 0.097145191412725, 0.292469758233477, 
    0.495218389282222, 0.703194412307631, 0.909770485345668, 
    1.10146639181104, 1.26832925378148, 1.40180248390486, 1.50499863779708, 
    1.58976612056803, 1.66550728596222, 1.73760118083855, 1.81589554303689, 
    1.90721508935673, 2.01376994777457, 2.12983243693232, 2.23652373309107, 
    2.32254626761092, 2.38054357596528, 2.40810045535242, 2.40394926714677, 
    2.36686870916879, 2.29766870686011, 2.20318990716965, 2.09813260968445, 
    1.99570702750249, 1.90736988262587, 1.83720289917554, 1.78161187758373, 
    1.73983055853244, 1.70927792570621, 1.67988794712524, 1.64888910606142, 
    1.61361662041016, 1.57650953468424, 1.54372787913957, 1.5244314606538, 
    1.52330649732676, 1.54270508686956, 1.58143977064381, 1.636473487204, 
    1.70950429045165, 1.8033824724133, 1.92033405775614, 2.05384342976532, 
    2.18750215114725, 2.30790921788468, 2.40321870289172, 2.45883788394123, 
    2.47015967697281, 2.44077592149473, 2.37892289121748, 2.29041335774065, 
    2.18002829826845, 2.04966058535416, 1.89526484626084, 1.71171242741373, 
    1.49132081196869, 1.23396310133448, 0.95500954396001, 0.667632997103173, 
    0.38512077599491, 0.123847240601854, -0.110820120876213, 
    -0.325945037178951, -0.532885924719711, -0.742469835797991, 
    -0.962562120790832, -1.19596460888606, -1.44178959331716, 
    -1.69506549562133, -1.94534305483521, -2.18614411237883, 
    -2.40568264717123, -2.60218120721895, -2.77649129664741, 
    -2.92915604423611, -3.06183666455997, -3.17633945440348, 
    -3.27075283510883, -3.34427994841041, -3.39786295278141, 
    -3.43425773685353, -3.45015093218111, -3.44982594478056, 
    -3.43952908619572, -3.42325877405017, -3.3990465071641, -3.35731024625162, 
    -3.28947270437373, -3.19835930400911, -3.09107293257786, 
    -2.98055307462963, -2.88021428074092, -2.80276150187654, 
    -2.75309025614095, -2.73325794972305, -2.7383769416982, -2.75955864571761, 
    -2.79454299208424, -2.84780817145616, -2.92526145550618, 
    -3.02606844521819, -3.13610028523395, -3.24823094670719, 
    -3.35088783781275, -3.44130572873659, -3.51962222582804, 
    -3.58702568846841, -3.64477003478028, -3.69595013747865, 
    -3.74444364567029, -3.78928382057047, -3.82385598846015, 
    -3.84705287468454, -3.8533823819126, -3.84413871661519, -3.8208728402198, 
    -3.78328712769685, -3.73161338369486, -3.66873492116964, 
    -3.59810850476349, -3.51953651265736, -3.42816920472332, 
    -3.32424549358071, -3.21433654038894, -3.1106716969322, -3.02284837678458, 
    -2.95792586222043, -2.92245560276176, -2.92011630212311, 
    -2.95123964026695, -3.01418271871464, -3.10488014168443, 
    -3.21901482408042, -3.34577526567369, -3.47824389913844, 
    -3.60475459912302, -3.72016390758787, -3.82157566853097, 
    -3.90720269237743, -3.97714463557551, -4.0317774412849, -4.070071700155, 
    -4.09450454867099, -4.10700019098849, -4.11024913380821, 
    -4.10123489846076, -4.07776077086166, -4.04575609527759, 
    -4.0141144656488, -3.98773564407337, -3.95746943231781, -3.92304814843235, 
    -3.89232130775218, -3.87372958711487, -3.87265757794753, 
    -3.87838887453369, -3.87841365989132, -3.86578511177274, 
    -3.84037936211251, -3.8029346932891, -3.75199765045956, -3.6847316629871, 
    -3.60155934204821, -3.50339422489437, -3.38352798832636, 
    -3.22655437552623, -3.02125418814082, -2.75647914196206, 
    -2.43327481949344, -2.06824701900987, -1.68047086696324, 
    -1.28213769516684, -0.886240220676704, -0.500970059658314, 
    -0.12444000017868, 0.250991728630396, 0.623774616743511, 
    0.977709952219271, 1.29524721749485, 1.55606175102286, 1.74531832376017, 
    1.83966118036697, 1.84292431839432, 1.77940743062681, 1.67393618451536, 
    1.55755710494071, 1.44205554045755, 1.32670507088405, 1.20789781376152, 
    1.09171590771403, 0.987997471256861, 0.901897811783634, 0.829621803641423, 
    0.762741121859925, 0.699109063115515, 0.639246070171836, 
    0.583762561480121, 0.534201502943503, 0.487081766112105, 
    0.442650388764974, 0.407905770403289, 0.388964336776255, 
    0.381774987131507, 0.378025230385383, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Vehicle.ID", "Frame.ID", 
"gap.dist", "relative.v"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 421135:421481)
```

### Code used for plot:

```
ggplot(data= df, mapping = aes(x=relative.v, y=gap.dist)) + geom_point()
```

This plot is only for 1 vehicle and there are about 1300 vehicles. I want to find the similar coordinates and label their locations and ALL rows in between as "oss" i.e. part of oscillation. Also, I want to subset this data frame so that all those vehicles which don't have similar coordinates i.e. oscillation loop are filtered out.

## Sample Data Frame

I tested some code on a  sample data below:

```
my.df <- data.frame(vehid = rep(c(2,3), each = 10),
                    frameid = rep(1:10,2),
                    relative.v = c(50,52,53,55,48,45,40,47,50,51, 50:59),
                    gap.dist = c(10,12,13,15,9,7,6,9,10,10, 15:24 ))
```

## What I tried

I achieved the end result by approaching the problem step by step but I am sure that this is not the most efficient way and there must be a quicker way to do this.

```
# Duplicated Relative Velocity
my.df <- ddply(my.df, .(vehid, relative.v), transform, dup = duplicated(relative.v), dup2 = duplicated(gap.dist))

#Labelling the similar coordinates
my.df <- ddply(my.df, .(vehid), transform, oss = ifelse(dup==T & dup2==T, 'oss', '.'))

# Labelling the first occurrence of similar coordinates
my.df[which(my.df$dup & my.df$dup2)-1,]$oss <- 'oss'

# Ordering by frameid
my.df <- ddply(my.df, .(vehid), function(x) x[with(x, order(frameid)),])

# Filtering out the vehicles with no oscillation
my.df <- subset(my.df, !ave(my.df$oss!='oss', my.df$vehid, FUN=all))
```

## Question

My code is good for sample data frame but for the `df` it doesn't work. Obviously the last step is not applicable for `df` and that's not the main concern. I want to create the `oss` column in `df` similar to `my.df` that marks the 2 rows which have approximately same `gap.dist` and `relative.v`. Please help!

Comment: It might make sense for you to convert your coordinates to a ```SpatialLinesDataframe``` object.  The points will be interpolated and your would be able to see where they approximately cross.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comment. I can see in the plot where the points approximately cross but there are 1300 unique `Vehicle.ID`s. I want to code this part where I don't have to manually find the starting and ending frame of similar x,y coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want speed, I think `data.table` is the way to go.  Especially since you have so many groups to do this to.

```
#Bring in data.table and set my.df as data.table
require(data.table)
setDT(my.df)

#Label is oss or not if there is a duplicated
my.df[ , oss  := 1*(.N > 1), by=list(vehid,relative.v,gap.dist)]

#Only keep vehicle ids with a duplicate
my.df[ , keep  := max(oss), by=vehid]
my.df <- my.df[keep!=0]

#Find the starting and stopping points
my.df[oss==1 , min.frameid := min(frameid), by=vehid] 
my.df[ , min.frameid := min(min.frameid,na.rm=T), by=vehid] 
my.df[ , max.frameid := max(frameid*oss), by=vehid] 

#Make oss 1 in between all stopping points
my.df[ , oss := 1*(between(frameid,min.frameid,max.frameid)), by=vehid]
```

Edit due to change in OP:

The other data your posted seems to imply that you don't really have duplicates for relative.v and gap.dist, but you have near duplicates.  You might want to try sorting the data by closest differences and figure out at what difference threshold you are willing to say that the points are the same.

```
#Sort data and look at absolute difference between closest points
my.df <- my.df[order(Vehicle.ID,relative.v,gap.dist)]
my.df[ , gap.dist.diff := c(NA,abs(diff(gap.dist))), by= Vehicle.ID]
my.df[ , relative.v.diff := c(NA,abs(diff(relative.v))), by= Vehicle.ID]
```

Next steps:

```
#Give rank order to data
my.df[ , newID := .I]

#Sort data other way
my.df <- my.df[order(Vehicle.ID,relative.v,gap.dist,decreasing=T)]

#Change values if within threshold
my.df[ , relative.v2 := ifelse(gap.dist.diff < 0.5 & relative.v.diff<0.2, relative.v[ID+1],relative.v)]

my.df[ , gap.dist2 := ifelse(gap.dist.diff < 0.5 & relative.v.diff<0.2, gap.dist[ID+1],gap.dist)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If the difference threshold for `gap.dist` is 0.5 and `relative.v` is 0.2, how can I reflect that in the code. I know I must first try to do this on my own but I don't know much about `data.table`. Thanks again for your feedback.